# Error while building decision tree using C5.0 in R language

Tags: r, decision-tree, c5.0

Here, I am predicting the type of glass based on its chemical content.chemical contents are input which are of numeric type(Ri,Na etc) and type of glass is output(Typec) which is factor.After building model using C5.0 I am getting error 
like

> "Error: Tree models only"

This is my code:

```
train=datax[sample(nrow(datax),80,replace=F),]

test=datax[!(1:nrow(datax))%in%as.numeric(row.names(train)),]

model=C5.0(Typec~.,data=train,rules=T, ntree= 50)

plot(model)
```

Here after running the plot instruction Im getting error mentioned.

Comment: What is the error? Are you sure the model was built successfully? Any errors or warning before the `plot()` command?

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your data? Like `dput(datax)`.

Comment: @AntoniosK ya there was no error while building model and there were no warning before plot instruction.And i got 0.83 of accuracy in confusion matrix

Comment: @RLave sure I will.

Comment: Is every value in `Typec` "y"? Can you check with `table(train$Typec)`?

Comment: FYI that's not very useful data for us, paste here the output from `dput(head(train))`

Comment: Try to build and plot the model without `rules=T`. Check more info here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/vignettes/C5.0.html where it mentions that rules based models have no plot methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
model=C5.0(Typec~.,data=train,rules=T, ntree= 50)
```

Remove "rules = T" argument and then you'll be able to plot the graph

Comment: But will it be the desired model?

Comment: Anyway I'm getting the error "'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"